# Bootstrap Group By V2 overrides hidden property of table asp.net core razor

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I am using the Bootstrap Group By V2 extension for an asp.net core razor application. Using the hidden property, I am hiding some of the table columns:

```
                <td hidden="@Model.IsHidden">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.something)
                </td>
```

It's working as expected until I start using the Group By extension:

```
                <table id="table" class="table table-hover" data-group-by="true" data-group-by-field="@Model.GroupByColumnName">
                    <thead></thead>
                </table>
```

The grouping is working as expected but now all columns are being displayed even if their property is set to hidden. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the CSS `display` property to hidden or show the cell content. Code like this:

```
            @{
                var showOrhidden = Model.IsHidden ? "none" : "block";
            }
            <td style="display:@showOrhidden"> 
                      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.something) 
            </td>
```

Besides, if using `display:none`, the cell will disappear, it might change the table structure, so, you could add a `<div>` tag in the `td` cell:

```
            @{
                var showOrhidden = Model.IsHidden ? "none" : "block";
            }
            <td> 
                 <div style="display:@showOrhidden">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.something) 
                 </div>
            </td>
```